# Spatiotemporal patterns in neural networks

Tags: neuroscience, bioinformatics, literature, computational-model, electrical-stimulation

It turns out that my work in nonlinear dynamics directly maps to a close variant of the Integrate and Fire model. My model produces spatiotemporal patterns that resemble foam. I have to stress that this is  the result of an exceedingly simple model of neuronal activity.

The plot below visualizes the voltage levels of a network of neurons. Yellow is high, purple is low.
[image]

I am wondering is these patterns are relevant to the computational neuroscience community. To this end, I am looking for literature describing spatiotemporal patterns in (preferably biological) neural systems.

I am especially interested in any work that  proposes metrics that characterise such patterns since this would allow for a quantitative comparison with my results.

Forgive me is this seems trivial to you, but coming form complex systems theory I did my best and found nothing.

Comment: Maybe look at the neural correlation literature? It often involves looking at statistical structures (patterns) of population codes.

Comment: I will take a look as you suggest.  The term population codes is very useful to me. Can you make your direction more precise (specific book/paper)? I know I am asking for a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I haven't looked at this sort of literature for a long time, but here are some thoughts with which to start.

Your question is about "spatiotemporal patterns" of neural systems. One of the first things that comes to mind is [neural oscillations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_oscillation) (e.g. [alpha waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_wave)). This is essentially looking for the presence of "frequency patterns" in the neural system. This has a huge amount of literature.

Another methodology that comes to mind is the graph-theoretic approach. In essence, functional or anatomical activity is used to build a graph, which can be analyzed for patterns (i.e. special properties of the graphs of neural systems that are, say, shared across species). One paper: [*Complex brain networks: graph theoretical analysis of structural and functional systems* by
Bullmore and Sporns](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Olaf_Sporns/publication/285708959_Complex_brain_networks_Graph_theoretical_analysis_of_structural_and_functional_systems/links/56a2476b08ae1b65112c86e9/Complex-brain-networks-Graph-theoretical-analysis-of-structural-and-functional-systems).

Separately, I might think about the neural correlations literature. Essentially, this is analyzing a neural population by examining the correlation structure of its members, and looking for patterns within it (i.e. that characterize the *population code* of the system). Two review papers: [*Neural correlations, population coding, and computation* by Averbeck et al](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e0a5/4e647c24f29c7b7ccd910c550ca87f79b03a.pdf)
and [*Measuring and interpreting neural correlations* by Cohen and Kohn](http://www.nature.com/neuro/journal/v14/n7/full/nn.2842.html?foxtrotcallback=true).
For a review on population codes, see [*Information processing with population codes* by Pouget et al](ftp://ftp.sys.toronto.edu/cs/ftp/public_html/dist/zemel/Papers/popCodeReview.pdf).
This notion is sort of orthogonal to the notion of *sparse coding* in neural networks, more prevalent in sensory perception.

Sorry if this is broad, but then again I feel the question is quite broad as well. If you have more specific questions, let me know.

Comment: This is broad, just like the question is. As someone coming form a different field, this is what I wanted, general directions. Thank you.